# How do you use the zfs encryption recovery key

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, zfs

I've installed ubuntu 21.10 using the graphical installer and I chose to use a ZFS root install with encryption using the GUI options (without doing the advanced stuff).  At some part of the process I recorded a "recovery key" - 48 digits (i.e. 0 -> 9).  How do you use that key?

- I've tried typing it in as the decryption pass phrase - that does not work.  (It's possible I mistyped it, but I did try a few times)
- After a few tries I dropped to the initramfs dropbox, which has the zfs command available.  I tried:

  - `zfs load-key -L prompt rpool` but it won't do a prompt at the terminal.
  - `zfs load-key -L file:///tmp/key.txt rpool` (where I'd put the digits from the recover key in `/tmp/key.txt`) but I was told the key had to be 32 bytes, not 48 bytes.

I've done quite a bit of web search and failed to find **how** to use the recovery key.